# How to remove specifics files from Maven Shaded plugin

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to generate Uber Jar using [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-shade-plugin-1.4/examples/includes-excludes.html) and i want to exclude some resources from the shaded jar and include some of specified artifact.But following exclude resources are bundled with it.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample.auto</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample.manual</groupId>
        <artifactId>sample-manual</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Distribute</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                                <filters>
                                    <filter>
                                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                            <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                                            <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                                            <exclude>com/myproject/auto/**</exclude>
                                            <exclude>org/**</exclude>
                                            <exclude>/*.png</exclude>
                                            <exclude>/*.html</exclude>
                                            <exclude>/*.jpeg</exclude>
                                            <exclude>com/google/common/**</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </filter>
                                </filters>
                                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                                <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Also i need to include `com.sample.auto` related artifact only into my uber jar. Please let me know where i made the mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filters on the artifacts as looking into your code should ideally be:

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
            <exclude>LICENSE</exclude> <!--if this is same as above, not required-->
            <exclude>/*.png</exclude>
            <exclude>/*.html</exclude>
            <exclude>/*.jpeg</exclude>
            <exclude>com.myproject.auto:**</exclude> <!--to exclude all the artifacts from com.myproject.auto group-->
            <exclude>org:**</exclude><!--exclude all artifacts under group org-->
            <exclude>com.google.common:**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </filter>
</filters>
```

OR in case you are looking to fine grain the classes from the dependent artifacts, then you can apply multiple filters like

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
            <exclude>LICENSE</exclude> <!--if this is same as above, not required-->
            <exclude>/*.png</exclude>
            <exclude>/*.html</exclude>
            <exclude>/*.jpeg</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <artifact>com.myproject.auto:*<artifact>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/myproject/auto/**</exclude> <!--to exclude a set of classes from the project structure-->
       </excludes>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <artifact>org:*<artifact>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>org/**</exclude> <!--though the artifact naming needs to be refined for this-->
       </excludes>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <artifact>com.google.common:**<artifact>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/google/common/**</exclude> <!--exclude classes from the respective artifacts-->
       </excludes>
    </filter>
</filters>
```

There are pretty useful [examples to exclude-include configurations](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) on Apache documentation as linked by you itself.

Comment: What's the difference from the question?

Answer (score 1):

Found easy way to exclude include artifacts from Uber Jar.As @nullpointer mentioned above can use filters to do that.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                        <exclude>LICENSE</exclude>
                        <exclude>*:*</exclude> // exclude all artifacts
                        <exclude>com.sample.manual:*</exclude> // exclude specific artifact
                    </excludes>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com.sample.auto:*</include> //include only com.sample.auto
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Apache Maven Shade Plugin v3.4.1)

```
<filters>
    <filter>
        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
        <excludes>
            <!-- exclude all proto files recursively -->
            <exclude>**/*.proto</exclude> 
        </excludes>
    </filter>
</filters>
```