# Make an executable JAR from a maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a question about using Apache Maven: I built a very simple Maven-based project. This works fine so far.
Now I want to make an executable JAR file from my target file. The problem here seems to be that the dependencies (external libraries) are not packaged together with my app.

I've already googled and found the maven-assembly-plugin. That actually does exactly what I want, but seems to be somewhat inflexible, since the dependencies are not automatically resolved and I can not specify file filters, etc. (or only with much effort over assembly.xml).
What I really like is the solution of spring-boot-maven-plugin, so automatically determine all linked JAR files and put in a lib folder. Now my little project is not a Spring application, so Spring Boot might not be suitable for me, right?
So what would interest me: Is there a way to get a similarly structured and executable JAR archive as spring-boot-maven-plugin builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html). It packages your dependencies inside your jar and you can specify the Java packages to exclude

Comment: First of all - thank you for the great tip. The plugin works very well. But I have one more question: Can I only exclude Java packages or also files contained in the packages, e.g. if someone has packed README files and I do not need them in my archive?

Comment: Acording to this link, you can also exclude resource files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040071/how-to-remove-specifics-files-from-maven-shaded-plugin